# How to Connect SQL Server Express 2008 to MS Access 2003

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2003

Im trying to connect the two applications above. I've already set up the database on the SQL Server to act as the back-end for the overall application and I need MS Access 2003 to act as the front end.

I managed to do it using MS Access 2007 which was quite simple.So, when you create the database does it have to be saved as a .adp file in order to connect to the SQL Server? Or would a normal .mdb file work? From what I've read this isnt the case and you need to use a .adp file - can someone confirm this?

Thanks

Comment: No, a normal mdb will work perfectly fine. Just link the tables from sql server.

Comment: Hello again Remou :) Do you mean import them? Also I headed down the ADP route and the SQL Server isn't visible - it's definitely running though (the server that is)

Comment: No, I mean link them. Use get external data and ODBC.

Comment: Ok - I followed your advice but the server isn't listed so I manually typed it in CAPS which did take me to the next screen (Selecting the authentication to use). I matched the settings used for MS Access 2007 but it failed

Comment: Got it working Remou, though it certainly wasn't as clean as what it is in Access 2007. When it listed the tables it asked me to select a PK for every one of them - all 49 :/ Thanks for your help